# How to take backup of StarTeam project

Tags: starteam

I have a project repositiory on Start Team server.
I need to take regular back up the same.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The Star team backup steps are given in the Appendix C of the “The StarTeam Administrator’s Guide.pdf”

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by backing up the Project.  If you mean backing up the entire repository then StarTeam makes this really easy.  You just need a snapshot of the DB and a full copy of the repository files (full steps are documented.)  However, if you mean backing up a specific Project in the repository, and ONLY that Project, with all history intace, then this is not currently possible--or at least it is a major challenge.

StarTeam used to have an ability to Import/Export projects but they discontinued support and development of that tool years ago.  If you wish to back up a single Project independent of the rest of the server, then this is still possible, and useful in the case where you want to split the repository into a separately managed repository.  Here is how to do that:

1. Create a duplicate repository including all of the repository files.
2. Delete everything from the clone except for the Project(s) that you want to split off -- note that in StarTeam 2011 the Project Delete was broken, so you may need to do this in a direct SQL query which marks the projects/views as deleted.  Contact Support if you run into problems deleting manually, especially if you have a large repository.
3. Once your clone has been pruned of unnecessary projects, run the Online Purge tool until all projects and respective files have been removed from the DB and the Vault.
4. You can now change what you need to change on the new repository, such as the users, groups, security, etc. without affecting the first repository.
5. Once you have validated the new repository is working properly, you can then run a similar process on the first repository to get rid of the projects that were split off.

Another potential use for this is if you had reached end of life for a project and you wanted to keep it offline and backed up but wanted it to be restorable with full history on demand (for regulatory purposes, etc.) while being freed up to remove it from the active repository so you can make other projects run faster.  Though this is probably best done in batches of projects as the process is currently quite labor intensive to perform.